# How to select everything inside a div?

Tags: css

HTML

```
<div id="div01">
<div id="div02"></div>
<div id="div03"></div>
<div id="div04"></div>
</div>
```

divs 02 03 and 04 have different position, size and other attributes, but they all should have the same border;

```
#div01 *{
    border:thin solid red;
}
```

Doesn't work. Is there a way at all ?

Comment: Could you add the html, just so we know 100% what you are doing - just to make sure it's not an html issue.

Comment: Pretty sure that should work, but why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: can you share your div code

Comment: @ysth: An element doesn't need to be a block to have a border.

Comment: @BoltClock: right, sorry

Comment: What "doen't work" exactly means? Borders are not displayed at all? Can your recreate your problem on JSFiddle?

Comment: you want to all div's similar  border and not on outer div 'div01'. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code would work perfectly fine.

**Your problem must be:**

- A typo
- No elements satisfying the criteria (#div01 *) i.e., no elements inside #div01

Answer (score 1):

As jsbookmarklets.com said above. I should just work. See the rule in action in this image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmUfH.png

May be provide the actual html markup and community can help you out. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
#div01 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

or

```
#div01 {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red; 
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

I would by the way also recommend that you use hex values for colours (#000000 for black, #ffffff for white and so on).

Comment: This puts the border on the div itself.

Comment: How many other alternatives are there?

Comment: excuse me please, it was a typo error. Thanks. Solved.